# Somar os dados de uma coluna do sql c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Meu problema é o seguinte: eu preciso somar as horas totais do funcionário que estão no banco, já numa coluna separada. Só pra deixar claro, as horas que o funcionário trabalhou no dia já estão prontas, quero somar essas horas totais.
Obs: Acredito que seja algo muito fácil, mas como recém estou começando a "programar" não estou conseguindo resolver isto.

```
using (PontoEntities entity = new PontoEntities())
        {
            Colaboradores cola1 = entity.Colaboradores.Where(cn => cn.Nome == strFunc).FirstOrDefault();
            var regs = entity.Batidas.Where(cn => cn.Codigo == cola1.ID);
            if (regs != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in regs)
                {
                    TimeSpan cont = TimeSpan.Parse(item.HorasTotais);;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} horas trabalhadas", cont);
                }
                Console.Read();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura `TimeSpan` suporta adição por meio do método `Add`, você pode fazer isso ao recorrer todo o loop. Pelo que entendi no seu código, `cont` é a hora trabalhada em uma linha da coluna, pois bem, some tudo no mesmo loop:

```
using (PontoEntities entity = new PontoEntities())
    {
        Colaboradores cola1 = entity.Colaboradores.Where(cn => cn.Nome == strFunc).FirstOrDefault();
        var regs = entity.Batidas.Where(cn => cn.Codigo == cola1.ID);
        if (regs != null)
        {
            // Cria um TimeSpan zerado
            TimeSpan totalTrabalhado = new TimeSpan();
            foreach (var item in regs)
            {
                TimeSpan cont = TimeSpan.Parse(item.HorasTotais);
                // Soma com o span atual no loop "item"
                totalTrabalhado.Add(cont);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} horas trabalhadas", cont);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} é o total de horas trabalhadas", totalTrabalhado.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Tente assim usando o sum do LINQ
    using (PontoEntities entity = new PontoEntities())
    {
        Colaboradores cola1 = entity.Colaboradores.Where(cn => cn.Nome == strFunc).FirstOrDefault();
        var regs = entity.Batidas.Where(cn => cn.Codigo == cola1.ID);
        if (regs != null)
        {
            TimeSpan soma = regs.Sum(x => x.HorasTotais)
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refatorei um pouco seu código, mas com comentário afim de melhorar sua escrita.

```
// PontoEntites é um Contexto de repositório ou banco de dados
// Então, quando instancia um PontoEntities ele retorna um Contexto, e não um Entity
// Uma entidade compôe um contexto
using (var ctx = new PontoEntities())
{
    // Nomenclatura de variaveis devem mostrar qual dado ela representa com clareza
    var colaborador = ctx.Colaboradores
                         // Em expressões, é "OK" encurtar as variaveis, para evitar
                         // colisão com variaveis externas, mas evite quando possivel
                         .FirstOrDefault(col => col.Nome == nomeColaborador);
                         // Colocar o tipo da variavel em seu nome é uma má prática

    // O uso do plural na nomenclatura é importante para deixar claro que 
    // representa uma coleção, e não apenas uma unidade do dado.
    // Mas tente nunca usar sufixo "Lista" como "ListaDeHoras" ou algo do tipo.       
    var horas = ctx
        // Entenda melhor a Linguagem Obliqua do seu negócio. 
        // Um colaborador "Bate o Ponto", então vc persiste os Pontos e não Batidas
        // Salvo se for um sistema de bar de coctails :)
        .Pontos
        // Codigo != Id. Codigo é uma informação fornecida, como Codigo de Barras,
        // Codigo de Area, Codigo de Acesso. A nomenclatura "Codigo" não deve ser usada
        // para Identificação, para isso, use "Id". 
        // Para "identificação" ou "chave primária", sempre use Id
        // Ex: Ponto.Id, e para relacionar use como sufixo, Ponto.ColaboradorId
        .Where(ponto => ponto.Id == colaborador.Id)
        // Sempre que possivel, reduza o trafego de dados entre seu repositorio de dados
        // e sua aplicação. Seu repositorio pode te entregar o total de horas, sem precisar
        // trafegar todo historico de Pontos. Isso aumenta performance e reduz complexidade
        // da sua aplicação
        .Sum(ponto => ponto.Horastotais);

    // Use Debug.WriteLine para criar logs em tempo de debugging
    // Esse é um output não bloqueante, e é certo que quando compilar 
    // seu código para release - produção - esse trecho não será incluído.
    // Vc pode ver suas saída pela janela Output / Debug
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} horas trabalhadas", horas);
 }
```